# Fetching files from AWS S3 - AWS::S3::NoConnectionEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to fetch some files from my S3 bucket to my `Rails 3` Application and stream them to the browser

In my Gemfile

```
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
```

and I also have configured my `s3.yml`

```
development:
  bucket: my_unique_bucket
  access_key_id: my_key
  secret_access_key: my_super_key
test:
  bucket: my_unique_bucket
  access_key_id: my_key
  secret_access_key: my_super_key
production:
  bucket: my_unique_bucket
  access_key_id: my_key
  secret_access_key: my_super_key
```

Then in my controller I try to `find` the file inside the containing folder in the bucket

```
s3File = S3Object.find "My.pdf","PDFs"
```

but in the browser I get

```
AWS::S3::NoConnectionEstablished
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're establishing the connection to Amazon before your request.

Ex.
     AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id => 'ID',
      :secret_access_key => 'KEY'
      )

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is the right way, I think there should be an automatic connection trough `Rails` between `S3` and the `gem` but so far this is working good... still the `s3.yml` it now doing anything around here...